# Does $\sqrt[x!]{x}$ converge? If yes, to what?

Tags: convergence-divergence

> Does $\sqrt[x!]{x}$ converge? If yes, to what?

I couldn't find any solutions to it. If anybody could show to what it converges or diverges, then I would appreciate it!

Comment: What is your function?   It's hard to parse.   Are you defining $x!$ via the Gamma function when $x\not \in \mathbb N$?  Something else?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: In this case I thought of it as x  an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the answer is $1$. This can be easily proven by using the identity $f(x)=e^{\ln(f(x))}$